# Cant add numbers to the products in my c# program

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a shopping list and add different items to it but I have no idea how to add the price of the item also and the get the result.

This is the code I'm using that is currently giving me this error, "Input string was not in the correct format"

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<string> Items;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new List<string>();
    }

    private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double num;
        num = double.Parse(txtItems.Text);


        Items.Add(txtItems.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        for(int i =0;i< Items.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Items[i] + num);
        }

    }
```

Comment: whats the value of  txtItems.Text

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: This sounds more like a Culture/decimal separator problem. Did you tried using a `,` or a `.`  in `txtItems.Text`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to associate two values, like the name and a price, you should create a class that holds these two values. If you name this `class Item`, then you can store a `List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();` with all of the items.

I suggest that you read more about classes to understand how this works.